# Azure Pipelines iOS Fastlane beta hangs and fails because of timout

Tags: xcode, azure-pipelines, fastlane

I am Using Azure Pipelines to build and deploy the Flutter Application.
I connect my Mac Mini as an Agent to the Azure Pipelines.
Agent Version: 2.173.0

Just as pretext it worked earlier. I am not sure which version it was, but the fact is now it is not working.

Under the hood, it is using Fastlane to

- build
- download signatures - Fastlane plugin
- sign and upload to TestFlight -  - Fastlane plugin

If I run the command from the terminal it is working fine:

```
bundle exec fastlane ios beta --verbose
```

But if I run it via pipeline it just stacks on a build log and just fails after an hour(timeout).

I have additionally checked during the run if any Dialog has shown up like xCode command tools install or anything. No, this was not the case.

The worst thing I could not determine what's going on because the logs hang as well.

```
set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/{almostGotMe}/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-09-02/Runner\ 2020-09-02\ 07.43.05.xcarchive archive | tee /Users/{almostGotMe}/Library/Logs/gym/Runner-Runner.log | xcpretty
```

Comment: Do you mean you can successfully build your Flutter Application in the earlier agent version? If yes, please try to update the agent to the latest version `2.174.1`, which fixes some errors about Workspace ID, check if you still have same issue.

Comment: Yes, Earlier it was building OK. I will try to update an agent.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Update to latest agent fixes the problem. Now the build is working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure Pipelines iOS Fastlane beta hangs and fails because of timout

Since the logs hang as well, we could not locate and analyze the cause of this issue. Fortunately, you could successfully build your Flutter Application in the earlier agent version.

So, the workaround to resolve this issue, we could re-install the old version agent to build this project.

To get the old version agent, we could check the logs of the previous successful pipeline. In the Initialize job, we can see the version information of the agent:

[image]

Then we could download old agent version from Github [azure-pipelines-agent](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases).

Comment: Updating to the latest version of agent helps.